# SendSignedTransaction TIMEOUT

Tags: web3js, evm, ethereumjs, ethereumjs-tx, sendsignedtransaction

I'm trying to sign data offline and then send signed transaction via web3.js

Here's my code snippet:

```js
const {sign} = require('@warren-bank/ethereumjs-tx-sign');
const {Loader} = require("loader-in-console");

var txData = {
    nonce: nonce,
    chainId: 80001,
    from: address1,
    to: address2,
    data: data,
    gas: 30000,
    gasPrice: 35000,
    value: '0x0'
}

const {rawTx} = sign(txData, privateKey);
var serializedTx = '0x' + rawTx.toString('hex');

let txResponse = await web3.eth.sendSignedTransaction(serializedTx);
console.log(txResponse);
```

It's timing out. What am I doing wrong here and is there an alternate way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Your gas price is extremely low. You can query the gas price with `web3.eth.gasPrice()`, when I did this I got `2000000000`. As your `35000` is very low it will take a long time (or potentially never) for a miner to pick up this transaction.

Comment: I'm using polygon testnet.

https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/

Comment: You `gasPrice`  is too low even for Polygon testnet. if this is too low the nodes will not pick your transaction. E.g. if you look at https://mumbai.polygonscan.com/tx/0x222ac5f84f22387da867afa0233a4fd3bdf0334adb849006cf5fa800ce198850 you see that the gas price is 250Gwei, which is way higher than what you set ;)

Comment: When I use that gas, I get `Error: Returned error: tx fee (500.00 ether) exceeds the configured cap (1.00 ether)`

Comment: You need to set a reasonable limit. According to the error you used 500 Ether, you should use a fraction of this. If you want to hardcode it use `gasPrice: 200_000_000_000`. But as mentioned before, the recommended way is to call `await web3.eth.gasPrice()` to get the value.

Comment: Yeah I'm setting whatever response await web3.eth.gasPrice() gets me.